# Scroll to List Item on Unordered List after new list item is added through mutation

Tags: html, reactjs, dom, apollo-client

I have data for a list that is coming from an apollo query.  The query fetches all of the data and the ul is used to display the list.  Ideally, I have a button that adds a new item to the end of the list and once that button is pressed and the new item added, I want to scroll to the item on the list.  My code is as follows.

```
const { data } = useQuery(getData);

<ul id="itemList">
    {data.map(item=> <li key={item.id} id={item.id}>{item.title}</li> )
</ul>
```

Somewhere else on the page, I have a button you can click to use the apollo mutation hook which adds a new item to the list and refetches the getData query.

```
const [createListItem, { loading, error }] = useMutation(createItem);

const resp = await createListItem({variables: {details: {title: "New Item"}}, refetchQueries: [{query: getData}]
```

I assumed once this was done and the item is added to the list (which I can see visibly), I can use the following code below to scroll to the item on my list programitically.  Id is automatically added by my DB once this item is added to the backend DB (MongoDB).

```
const listItem = document.getElementById(resp.data.createListItem.id);
listItem?.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
```

The listItem variable shows null.  This is most likely due to the DOM not refreshing before I try to scroll to the item.  If I hardcode an id that already exists (besides my newly created one), the auto scroll works.

How can I get the li document for the newly created item once added and query refetches and then scroll to it? Is there an "onchange" event or something like that I can listen for using addEventListener to search for my newly created item on the list and then scroll to it?

Thanks

Comment: If you are using `class` components, try adding the `scrollIntoView` code in the `componentDidUpdate` method.

Comment: Ive tried this.  Im using react hooks.  I tried using useEffect hook with re-render variable change.  That didnt work either.

`useEffect(()->{},[stateVariable])`

stateVariable is a place where I store the item details once created.  In useEffect, the stateVariable triggers a re-render when updated.  Even with that, the ul is a step behind.  I need to refresh the window for my scroll to work.  Its not instant.  

Im looking for a way to trigger my ul to update when li is dynamically added, which then has the list item available and therefore scrolls to it using the code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  Thanks for the componentDidUpdate suggestion.  I did this using React Hooks (useEffect and useState) .

To reference my original question above, once I add the item using the mutation hook, I store the id of the newly added item in state

```
const [addedItem, updateAddedItem] = useState("")
```

So to reference code in question above.

```
const resp = await createListItem({variables: {details: {title: "New Item"}}, refetchQueries: [{query: getData}]

updateAddedItem(resp.data.createListItem.id)
```

In the component where I am rendering my list, I use the useEffect hook.

```
  useEffect(() => {
        const listItem = document.getElementById(addedItem);
        listItem?.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
      }
    }
  }, [data]);
```

This way, when the data is updated, the list item is available in the DOM to scroll to.